# What "chgrp 0" do?

Tags: find, chgrp

I am analyzing one script and I cannot find online what `chgrp 0` mean in the following line:

```
find $1 -follow -exec chgrp 0 {}
```

so

`find $1` takes parameter,

`-follow` causes find to follow symlinks,

`-exec` executes the command,

`chgrp 0` change group ownership, **but what 0 do?**,

`{}` for all items found by the find command.

Please correct me if I am wrong with something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`chgrp 0 file` will change the group ownership of the file `file` to the group with GID `0` which in nearly all cases in Linux is the `root` group (in BSD, this is nearly always `wheel`).  So your `find` command will search in the path provided by the first positional parameter (`$1`) for all filesystem objects contained therein, follow any symbolic links to their targets, and make the group owner of those objects GID `0`, `root` (or `wheel`).

Comment: Pleased to have helped.  Welcome to U&L!  If this answered your question, please click the checkmark to the left of this answer to indicate that your question has been answered to your satisfaction.

Comment: On BSD systems, the group with GID zero will likely be the `wheel` group (which is the primary group of the `root` user).

Answer (score 1):

Basicly ownership of any file/directory in linux is stored in the in [inode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode). And it stored as an integers (integer for user, and second integer for group). It depends only on your NSS (e.g. /etc/passwd file, or ldap) which name it will show you in ls. Performing operation like `chgrp root file` system will take GID of "root" group (in my case it's 0) and write that 0 into inode. You can also make something like this:

```
# touch testfile
# chgrp 135543 testfile
# ls -l testfile
-rw-r--r--. 1 root 135543 0 Aug 21 18:05 testfile
# groupadd -g 135543 testgroup
# ls -l testfile
-rw-r--r--. 1 root testgroup 0 Aug 21 18:05 testfile
```

Comment: "Something". Fixed.

Comment: Yes, In my (beginners) opinion it is more logical to write `chgrp root file` than to assume that root group is number zero

Answer (score 0):

0 is the UID and GID of root. So as you are executing chgrp 0 you are changing the group ownership of the file/directory to root.